# I am making a recursive algorithm to return the length of the lowest row of a pyramid you are able to build with the input amount of blocks

Tags: javascript

It needs to still return the correct row in the case of a input number that doesn't make a full pyramid.
Inputs `old, Internal, lr` are all internal and shouldn't be required to fill in.

```
const pir = (Input, old, Internal, lr) => {
    console.log({
        Input, Internal, lr
    });
    if (Internal === undefined || lr === undefined || old === undefined) {
        Internal = 1;
        lr = 1;
        old = 1;
    }
    console.log({
        Input, Internal, lr
    });
    if ( ( Input === Internal ) || ( Input < Internal && old > Internal ) ) {
        return lr;
    } else {
        return pir(Input, Internal, Internal + (lr + 1), lr + 1)
    }
};
```

Comment: The algorithm work except for the part where you in put a number that isn't able to make a full algorithm

Comment: can you provide sample inputs and expected outputs?

Answer (score 2):

The condition `old > internal` is never going to be true.

You need to get the condition where there is an overrun only (not equality). When there is an overrun, return `lr - 1`, which is the previous value of `lr`, and which was OK:

```
if (Input < Internal) {
    return lr - 1; // Return previous value of lr (the last successful one)
}
```

Some other remarks:

- You can give parameters default values in the function heading
- Name your variables in camelCase (so not starting with a capital). It is common practice to reserve names with a starting capital (PascalCase) for constructors/classes.
- And as you see from the above simplification, you don't really need the `old` argument

So here is how the function could look:

```
const pir = (input, internal=1, lr=1) => {
    if (input < internal) {
        return lr - 1; // Return previous value of lr (the last successful one)
    } else {
        return pir(input, internal + lr + 1, lr + 1)
    }
};
```

Finally, the relationship between the size and the width of such a "pyramid" is a mathematical one. This relationship can be solved in terms of the width, and so we can write `pir` as:

```
const pir = input => Math.floor((Math.sqrt(1+8*input) -1)/2);
```